# Cells in DataGrid not display data at all

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I i'm trying to bind DataTable to DataGrid. But DataGrid have rows count like in DataTable and all cells are empty! What am I do wrong?

```
<DataGrid Name="ScheduleCommon" Margin="2,0,4,0" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.21,0.4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ФИО" Binding="{Binding Path = Name}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Специализация" Binding="{Binding apt.Specialisation}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Дата" Binding="{Binding apt.WorkDay, StringFormat=dd MM yyyy}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="С" Binding="{Binding apt.TimeBegin}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="До" Binding="{Binding apt.TimeEnd}"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
```

And

```js
>             InitializeComponent();
> 
>             this.sqlc = sqlc;
> 
>             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
>             cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Doctor.Name as 'ФИО', Specialisation.Specialisation                                  as 'Специализация', DoctorVisitingDay.WorkDay as'Рабочий день'," +
>                               " DoctorVisitingDay.TimeBegin as 'C', DoctorVisitingDay.TimeEnd as 'До' FROM Doctor, Specialisation, DoctorVisitingDay" +
>                               " WHERE Doctor.Specialisation = Specialisation.ID AND Doctor.ID = DoctorVisitingDay.IDDoctor";
>             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
>             cmd.Connection = this.sqlc;
>             adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
>             dtSch = new DataTable("Schedule");
>             adp.Fill(dtSch);            
>             
>             ScheduleCommon.ItemsSource = dtSch.DefaultView;
```

Comment: Your binding to the View model Directly not to a property AND setting the ItemSource. First try the first or the last not Both. Next thing is you'r binding the Columns to a Property of apt. That means your Collection should have that property.

Comment: @JPVenson, so if I bind to DataTable without class there is no way to do custom columns?